# Simple WebMvcTest fails with Spring Boot Missing SpringBootConfiguration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-mvc-test

**Test 1**

```
package test.java.rest.springframework.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootWebTest {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

   }
```

**Test 2**

```
package test.java.rest.springframework.test;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

public class TestWebApp extends SpringBootWebTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void testEmployee() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

}

}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:409)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:323)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:78)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:152)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I am trying to do a simple junit test for my mvc controller index page. I followed [Tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKD9E8KsQME&t=211s) But I am getting a missing springbootconfiguarion error? How can I create simple JUnit test with spring boot.

Comment: In what package is your main class that's annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`?

Comment: Answer is in your error only. you have to mention configuration in SpringBootTest. `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)` Try this. Also you can auto configure MockMvc with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your test class with `@ContextConfiguration`as below.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestBeanConfig.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty annotation

```
@SpringBootTest
```

is not enough. You need to declare the configuration classes the test should use. 
You can do it like this :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MyConfig1.class,MyConfig2.class })
```

I am not sure, if annotating the test super class works, so you may try to annotate the test class 'TestWebApp' directly.